# Group by not working as intended

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am facing a problem with GROUP BY clause, and the data is not showing up as I would like to have:

I have the data like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Company   | Division | Business Area | Unit   | Name Full  | ID |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 1    | Unit 1 | Customer 1 | 01 |
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 1    | Unit 1 | Customer 2 | 02 |
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 1    | Unit 2 | Customer 3 | 03 |
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 3    | Unit 3 | Customer 2 | 02 |
| Company 1 | Div 2    | Business 1    | Unit 1 | Customer 4 | 04 |
....
....
```

In UI, I would like to have it displayed like this:

```
Company 1, Div 1, Business 1, Unit 1
   -- Customer 1  01
   -- Customer 2  02
Company 1, Div 1, Business 1, Unit 2
   -- Customer 3 03
Company 1, Div 1, Business 3, Unit 3
   -- Customer 2 02
Company 1, Div 2, Business 1, Unit 1
   -- Customer 4 04
```

I tried the query, and if I try to group by only using company, div, business and unit then I get the error: 00979: not a group by expression as I am not using all columns as I used in SELECT, but then I don't get my required result.

Any idea how may I proceed?

Comment: This is not directly solvable using just a group by, please do some more research on how the 'group by' clause in sql works.  The correct way to do this also involves coding in the server environment that reads the data, or with javascript on the front-end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jaanna,

Your example dataset has 5 rows and your expected output contains 9 rows. Those extra 4 rows are aggregations per (company,division,business_area,unit) where name_full and id are being rolled up.

Your example data:

```
SQL> create table mytable (company,division,business_area,unit,name_full,id)
  2  as
  3  select 'Company 1', 'Div 1', 'Business 1', 'Unit 1', 'Customer 1', '01' from dual union all
  4  select 'Company 1', 'Div 1', 'Business 1', 'Unit 1', 'Customer 2', '02' from dual union all
  5  select 'Company 1', 'Div 1', 'Business 1', 'Unit 2', 'Customer 3', '03' from dual union all
  6  select 'Company 1', 'Div 1', 'Business 3', 'Unit 3', 'Customer 2', '02' from dual union all
  7  select 'Company 1', 'Div 2', 'Business 1', 'Unit 1', 'Customer 4', '04' from dual
  8  /

Table created.
```

The query:

```
SQL> select company
  2       , division
  3       , business_area
  4       , unit
  5       , name_full
  6       , id
  7    from mytable
  8   group by company
  9       , division
 10       , business_area
 11       , unit
 12       , rollup((name_full,id))
 13   order by company
 14       , division
 15       , business_area
 16       , unit
 17       , grouping(name_full) desc
 18       , name_full
 19  /

COMPANY   DIVISION BUSINESS_AREA UNIT   NAME_FULL  ID
--------- -------- ------------- ------ ---------- --
Company 1 Div 1    Business 1    Unit 1
Company 1 Div 1    Business 1    Unit 1 Customer 1 01
Company 1 Div 1    Business 1    Unit 1 Customer 2 02
Company 1 Div 1    Business 1    Unit 2
Company 1 Div 1    Business 1    Unit 2 Customer 3 03
Company 1 Div 1    Business 3    Unit 3
Company 1 Div 1    Business 3    Unit 3 Customer 2 02
Company 1 Div 2    Business 1    Unit 1
Company 1 Div 2    Business 1    Unit 1 Customer 4 04

9 rows selected.
```

You might want to conditionally display some column values or not, but I leave that as an exercise to you.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do can not be achieved using a "group by" query. Rather you can use "order by" like:

```
select * from table order by Company, Division, BusinessArea, Unit asc
```

hope it helps

edit:
Sorry that i couldn't make comment on florin's answer. Florin's answer is great also but it would be harder to process on it further on a web UI for example. If it's plsql and the output should be exactly what you've written in the question, you should use a loop to get the name and id of each Company, Division, BusinessArea, Unit group.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the environment, but typically GROUP BY queries require that every column be either a GROUP BY field or an aggregate field.

What You are trying to achieve looks more like an ORDER BY to me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   company, 
   division, 
   businessarea, 
   unit, 
   LISTAGG(fullname||' '||id , '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fullname)
from your_table
group by company, division, businessarea, unit
order by company, division, businessarea, unit
```

Comment: Thanks Florin for your response. I tried your solution, and for some reason I get "ORA-01489: result of string concetenation too long". This is quite unusual as none of the full names are over 4000 character

Comment: that's because some units contains too many customers, so the (concatenated)string becomes to large.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 

(
select Company, Division, BusinessArea,  Unit ,NameFull,ID 
       from t
union all
select distinct  Company, Division, BusinessArea,  Unit ,'' as NameFull,0 as ID 
       from t
) d 

order by Company, Division, BusinessArea,  Unit ,NameFull,ID
```

Comment: Produces approximately the same data set as my query, but with two full table scans.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a count for each member in the company/division/business area/unit set e.g.:

```
SELECT company,
    division,
    business_area,
    unit,
    name_full,
    ID,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY company, division, business_area, unit 
    ORDER BY  company, division, business_area, unit, name_full) AS rn
FROM t1
```

this should return:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
| Company   | Division | Business Area | Unit   | Name Full  | ID | rn |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 1    | Unit 1 | Customer 1 |  01 |1  |
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 1    | Unit 1 | Customer 2 |  02 |2  |
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 1    | Unit 2 | Customer 3 |  03 |1  |
| Company 1 | Div 1    | Business 3    | Unit 3 | Customer 2 |  02 |1  |
| Company 1 | Div 2    | Business 1    | Unit 1 | Customer 4 |  04 |1  |
```

Then in your ui you can loop through the results and display every record that has an rn = 1 as a header and then fullname & id, here's some psudo code

```
for each record loop
 if rn=1 
   display t1.division, t1.business_area
 end if
 display t1.name_full,id
end loop
```